# Grafana dashboard - last time a pod got terminate

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, victoriametrics

Is there any way to get back the time of the last termination.
The metric: "kube_pod_container_status_last_termination_reason" gives back a fresh data everytime, but i want to know when did that termination exactly happen.

What queries or transformation do i need to use?

Thanks a lot guys.

Merging my last termination and a random query just to fill out every spaces in a table, then try to find the last null value, so i know when did the termination happen.
Didn't get the expected result.

Comment: I don't think `kube_pod_container_status_last_termination_reason` will be enough for you, as theoretically it's possible for multiple pods to be terminated with the same reason, thus simple last change is not enough here..

Comment: Try using `tlast_change_over_time(kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason[d])`, where `[d]`  is the time interval on which you want to scan for the last change. See https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#tlast_change_over_time